# IOS5 - App running on Simulator but crashing on device

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, runtime-error

I'm developing my first application and it has come to a time to test it on a real device. I had an old iPhone 3GS in the office that I updated to the latest version of IOS.

When I try to launch the application on the iPhone simulator, everything works well. But then, I try to launch it on my device, and the application crashes with the error below :

```
2012-09-13 14:16:01.556 MyFirstApp[1702:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught
exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSCFString 0x15e2e0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: 
this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key testKey.'
```

I checked my build settings, which are as below :

[image]

I've also heard that it can come from some variables that are not properly set or deleted in IB, but I don't have any warnings about that...

Here's some code I'm using on the view concerned by the error :

```
@implementation HomeViewController {
    @private
    NSArray *_orders;
    __strong UIActivityIndicatorView *_activityIndicatorView;
}

@synthesize orderList = _orderList;

- (void)reload:(id)sender {
    [_activityIndicatorView startAnimating];

    [Order orderListWithBlock:^(NSArray *orders) {
        if (orders) {
            _orders = orders;
            [self.orderList reloadData];
        }
        [_activityIndicatorView stopAnimating];
    }];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self reload:nil];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Custom Cell Segment";
    static NSString *OtherCellIdentifier = @"Other Cell Segment";
    Order *o = [_orders objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if ([o.testKey isEqualToString:@""]) {
        [SOME STUFF]
    }
    else {
        [SOME OTHER STUFF]
    }
}
```

Does anyone knows where does the error can come from ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: once reset your simulator and run again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That may not be because of the simulator vs. device, but because you had **an old IBOutlet in Interface Builder that you deleted since**, but the connection is still present in the XIB. **Just open the XIB where you have that old IBOutlet "testKey" connection and remove the connection.**

Now for why your app worked on your simulator so far, this is because the XIB hasn't been recompiled, or some old XIB that you deleted from the sources are still in the build product from a previous build.

So I bet that **if you completely clean your project, removing the Build Directory and rebuilding from the beginning, you will have the same problem in the Simulator** and can thus reproduce it and debug it.

To do that, you may perform a "Clean" from the "Product" menu, or even better old the option key while opening this menu to select "Clean Build Folder…".
Sometimes it is not sufficient anyway, so you may instead delete the whole build folder from the Finder:

- Open the Organizer (menu "Window" -> "Organizer")
- Select the "Projects" tab at the top, then select your project on the left
- Click the "Delete" button next to the "Derived Data" zone.

This will delete your Build Output directory so that the next time you build your project it will recompile everything from scratch.

From there you may see your warning on the XIB file and you will observe that your application will also crash in the Simulator, meaning that is not a crash that is due to the device, but due to the fact that previous builds messed up your built application.
And you can fix this crash (by removing the old "testKey" outlet connection in the XIB) for both device and simulator.

Comment: First, thank for this answer ! I've forgot to mention that I'm using storyboarding. 1/ In IB, I checked the view concerned by the error, and I have no IBOutlet called `testKey`. 2/ I cleaned the project, recompiled and the behaviour is still the same. 3/ I deleted the derived data, and again, the same behaviour :(

Comment: I've put some code in my post, it could probably be a bit clearer with it.

Comment: Your code seems totally incoherent for me. For example when you call your `orderListWithBlock:` method, you pass an `NSArray* orders` as a parameter, and then affect `_orderList = orders` in the block. So I assume that `_orderList` is the same kind as `orders`, namely an `NSArray`. But then you call `reloadData` on `self.orderList` (which is according to the naming convention the property associated with the `_orderList` instance variable)... But `self.orderList` is an `NSArray`, not an `UITableView` ! So this is nonsense.

Comment: Moreover, are you sure that objects you retrive from your `_orders` array are `Order` objects? The exception let us suspect that it retrieve `NSString` objets, not `Order` objets. This is probably either because your `NSArray` do contain `NSString` objets, or because you have memory corruption (which is quite more likely, as you seem to confuse your `NSArray` and your `UITableView` as explained in my previous comment)

Comment: My bad, I've missed the c/p of that line. It should be better right now.

Comment: Are you using ARC? If not, you should retain the value you store in `_orders` (and release the old value before in case there is one). Or a more secure approach to make sure that you don't forget to do the retain/release dance is to use only `@property(retain) instead of instance variables (as the setter of the property will do the release+retain for you).

Comment: (1) Put a breakpoint in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method and first check if your crash really happens in this method when you try to access the `testKey` property of variable `o`. (2) Then check the class of the `o` variable to check if it is of the `Order` class and not an `NSString`. (3) It may be useful to add a "Exception Breakpoint" in your project to check the callstack just before the exception is thrown and understand where it crashes.

Comment: Hmm, after some investigations, it seems the error is located elsewhere. In the Order.m file, I'm using a `NSDate` and `NSDateFormatter` and the result is not the same on the simulator and on my device. On the simulator, I have : `13 Sep 2012 00:00:00` whereas on my device, I have `13 sept. 2012 00:00:00` :/

Comment: That's totally normal to have those different values, as the format of the date depend in the "International" settings of the phone (an iPhone in French and with the French setting in the Region format of the International settings will display dates differently as an iPhone in English). By the way, I don't get why it would crash your app (except if you parse the string yourself badly to do stuff, instead of relying on the `NSDate` itself and its `NSDateComponents`, and the parsing failure hasn't been handled in your code?)

Comment: It crashed because the API that I call only accept a date in English. With that, the middleware returned me a failure response that I didn't catched, the value testKey was not filled, and it crashed.

Comment: Ok so you just need to force the `locale` property of your `NSDateFormatter` to the english `NSLocale` then ;) Or force a given format with the `dateFormat` property (instead of using `timeStyle` and `dateStyle` that adapt to the user preferences and locale) !

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using interface builder for develop the user interface ,check the waring for IBOutlet
,You changed the name of any view. and also check the file Owner .

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere you are trying to access the property `testKey` using key value coding, but you are trying to access it on an object that does not have that property (more specifically you are trying to access it on an string).

Where and why this happens I have no idea as you have not posted any code.

Check your project for any access to `testKey` done via KVC (may even be due to something you put in a xib).

Comment: There's no KVC access to anything in that code. The problem comes from something that does a KVC access for key `testKey` or a keypath containing that key. It may or may not be in the code. If it's not in your code it's most probably out of something in your xib. Search for `testKey` in both the source files and the xib file itself.

Comment: In the view, I have a UITableView, which contains some CustomCells. In this CustomCell, I have a IBOutlet 'testKey', but nothing seems to be wrong with that, everything seems to be linked properly.

Comment: Well, it may not seem to be wrong, but connections done with an IBOutlet do use KVC, so that may be where the problem is. I say may because I have no idea how you are using that outlet nor if there is any other possible source of problems. All you say is that you have an outlet in custom cells of a table view. As you may guess that is too little information for me to understand how your xib is set up and how it links to the code.